# backbone.js - Having multiple instances of the same view

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I am having problems having multiple instances in of the same view in different div elements. When I try to initialize them only the second of the two elements appear no matter what order I put them in.

Here is the code for my view.

```
  var BodyShapeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    thingiview: null,
    scene: null,
    renderer: null,
    model: null,
    mouseX: 0,
    mouseY: 0,

events:{
  'click button#front' : 'front',
  'click button#diag' : 'diag',
  'click button#in' : 'zoomIn',
  'click button#out' : 'zoomOut',
  'click button#on' : 'rotateOn',
  'click button#off' : 'rotateOff',
  'click button#wireframeOn' : 'wireOn',
  'click button#wireframeOff' : 'wireOff',
  'click button#distance' : 'dijkstra'
},

initialize: function(name){
  _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'animate');

     scene = new THREE.Scene();
     camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 15, 400 / 700, 1, 4000 );
     camera.position.z = 3;
     scene.add( camera );
     camera.position.y = -5;

     var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(  0x202020 );
     scene.add( ambient );

     var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight( 0xffffff, 0.75 );
     directionalLight.position.set( 0, 0, 1 );
     scene.add( directionalLight );


     var pointLight = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 5, 29 );
     pointLight.position.set( 0, -25, 10 );
             scene.add( pointLight );

     var loader = new THREE.OBJLoader();
     loader.load( "img/originalMeanModel.obj", function ( object ) {

        object.children[0].geometry.computeFaceNormals();
        var  geometry = object.children[0].geometry;
                console.log(geometry);
        THREE.GeometryUtils.center(geometry);
        geometry.dynamic = true;
        var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xffffff, shading: THREE.FlatShading, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors });
        mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
        model = mesh;
        // model = object;
        scene.add( model );
     } );

     // RENDERER
     renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
     renderer.setSize( 400, 700 );
     $(this.el).find('.obj').append( renderer.domElement );

    this.animate();

},
```

Here is how I create the instances

```
var morphableBody = new BodyShapeView({ el: $("#morphable-body") });

  var bodyShapeView = new BodyShapeView({ el: $("#mean-body") });
```

Any help would be really appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `initialize`method, you access global variables instead of instance variables: `scene = new THREE.Scene();` will in fact reference `window.scene`.

Check this example

```
var BodyShapeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    scene:null,
    initialize:function(opts) {
        scene=opts.scene;
    }
});

var s1=new BodyShapeView({scene:'s1'});
var s2=new BodyShapeView({scene:'s2'});

console.log(window.scene);  //outputs s2
console.log(s1.scene); //outputs null
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K8tjJ/1/

Change these references to `this.scene`, `this.camera`, etc.

```
var BodyShapeView = Backbone.View.extend({
    scene:null,
    initialize:function(opts) {
        this.scene=opts.scene;
    }
});

var s1=new BodyShapeView({scene:'s1'});
var s2=new BodyShapeView({scene:'s2'});

console.log(window.scene); //outputs undefined
console.log(s1.scene); //outputs s1
```

http://jsfiddle.net/K8tjJ/2/

Additionally, `loader.load` uses a callback to process its results, you will (probably) lose the reference to `this` in the function. Try

```
var _this=this;
loader.load( "img/originalMeanModel.obj", function ( object ) {
...
_this.scene.add( _this.mesh ); // or _this.model if you prefer, but beware

});
```

Note that `this.model` is a special variable in Backbone.View and should be treated with care if you ever want to pass a model to your view.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @nikoshr this makes complete sense! The only problem I now have is that when adding the model to the scene in the loader function I receive this error. "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'add' of undefined " for this line this.scene.add( this.model );

Comment: @TrueWheel The joys of this in JS. I modified my answer, that should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `el` attribute only needs a jQuery style selector string. Try:

```
var morphableBody = new BodyShapeView({ el: "#morphable-body" });
var bodyShapeView = new BodyShapeView({ el: "#mean-body" });
```

**UPDATE**

Also, your problem may be that you're not using the `this` keyword when defining `scene`, `camera`, and `renderer`. It could be that the second view is overwriting the first view as a result. Try:

```
this.scene = new THREE.Scene();
this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 15, 400 / 700, 1, 4000 );

...

// RENDERER
this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
this.renderer.setSize( 400, 700 );
$(this.el).find('.obj').append( this.renderer.domElement );
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply and I'm afraid I still get the same problem where only one appears.

Comment: @TrueWheel is the first view being created at all? i.e. is it being rendered, then replaced by the second view? Or, is the first view not being rendered at all?

Comment: I think it is being replaced as in the console THREE.WebGLRenderer and THREE.Geometry are displayed twice. Thanks